# How to run a hql file from within hive terminal?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, hadoop, hive

I need to run an HQL file and do things based on the result. The HQL file creates a table. Below is how I'm calling the script from my bash script.

```
if echo -e "hive -f $table_create_file -hiveconf database='$hive_db' -hiveconf table='$hive_table_name' -hiveconf query='$hive_query'"
then 
      echo "success"
else
      echo "error message"
exit 100
fi
```

But this returns success even if the create table command inside the HQL file fails. I believe this is because I am not piping to the hive terminal. How can I handle this situation? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `hive` command returns success/fail return code depending upon the status of the execution, you can directly use it in the `if-clause` as

```
if hive -hiveconf database="$hive_db" -hiveconf table="$hive_table_name" -hiveconf query="$hive_query" -f "$table_create_file" 
then 
      echo "success"
else
      echo "error message"
      exit 100
fi
```

I have double-quoted all the variables for the `shell` to expand it on execution.